# How can I use Django template syntax in CSS selectors?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm pretty new to Django, and I've been wondering about this for a while.

Is there any way to put template syntax into a CSS selector, like this:

```
{% for i in list %}
    <!-- I know for a fact that 'list' has data in it -->
    <div id='div{{ forloop.counter }}'>test{{ forloop.counter }}</div>
    <style>
        #div{{ forloop.counter }} {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
{% endfor %}
```

And have it produce this code:

```html
<div id='div1'>test1</div>
<style>
  #div1 {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
<div id='div2'>test2</div>
<style>
  #div2 {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
<div id='div3'>test3</div>
<style>
  #div3 {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

I tried this, but the `<style>` tag just flat out refuses to work.

Is there a way to achieve this, and if so, how?

Comment: Are you sure that `list` contains data? What is the wrong result you get?

Comment: @Matthias The <style> tag seems to do nothing. I know for a fact that `list` has data, because I'm outputting the item in `list` (I made the code so it's as simple as it can be, with the error still being present.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, It's not possible to use template syntax in css

Comment: One can create dynamic CSS files with Django. But in this case it's not even a CSS file. Look at the tags, this is HTML.